# How to know if the next middleware in pipeline is executed? .Net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

Below is my `Configure` in `startup.cs`, there are a bunch of `middlewares` added in the pipeline, one of these middlewares is short circuiting the incoming requests but I am unable to debug the default .net core middlewares and since I am to debug the middlewares I dont understand from where my request is getting short circuit. How do I know which middleware is short circuiting my request?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseErrorHandlingMiddleware(options =>
        {
            // Log.Information("UseErrorHandlingMiddleware");

            options.AddResponseDetails = OverrideApiErrorResponse;
            options.IsDevelopment = Env.IsDevelopment();
        });

        if (!Env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
        app.UseLoggingScopeMiddleware();

        // Allow all methods, header and origin
        app.UseCors(x =>
        {
            // Log.Information("UseCors");

            x.AllowAnyHeader();
            x.AllowAnyMethod();
            x.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            Log.Information("Use(async (context");

            context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
            {
                NoCache = true,
                NoStore = true
            };
            await next();
        });

        app.UseResponseCompression();           

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
            DefaultContentType = "application/yaml",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Env.WebRootPath, "yaml")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/v2/yaml")
        });

        app.UseRaygun();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

        app.UseSwaggerDocuments();
    }
```

Comment: what you want basically requires that each middleware must have some id or name to be identifiable at runtime (when processing a request). I don't think it's supported in the current design of `asp.net core`. You can design your own middlewares to support that feature but the built-in and third-party middlewares don't have to support that as well as there is no standard way for them to be identifiable at runtime. What closest to your requirement is to know the stacktrace at the end of the request (for debugging) so that you may analyze to know which middleware short-circuits yours.

Comment: A general approach might be to binary search it by cutting half of the middlewares out and see if the problem is resolved. Keep repeating by keeping the half with the problem until you find it.

Answer (score 1):

Middlewares in `asp.net core` are not identified with any id or name for later referencing back at runtime when processing a request. At least that's how they are designed at the current time. For the purpose of debugging, we can however try injecting as much logs as possible each time entering and exiting a middleware. We can even introduce a ***request feature*** to store the last run middleware info, almost for the purpose of debugging.
It becomes complicated when you use inline middlewares registered with `Use`, `UseWhen`, `MapWhen`. With those middlewares, there are not any names attached for identifying (for the others, we may extract the method name with format like `Usexxx`) so we can only write some possible debugging info such as line number, filename (although even these info are not always capturable due to some bug or limitation in the framework).

The following code is not a perfect solution but a good approach that can be improved more, may be helpful in almost the cases and I believe it's the best that you can do to help debug better:

First we need some feature models:

```
public interface IMiddlewareInfo
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    IMiddlewareInfo NextMiddlewareInfo { get; }
}
public interface ILastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature : IMiddlewareInfo
{        
}
public class LastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature : ILastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int RegisteredLineNumber { get; }
    public string ConfigFile { get; }
    public LastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature(string name, int registeredLineNumber, string configFile)
    {
        Name = name;
        RegisteredLineNumber = registeredLineNumber;
        ConfigFile = configFile;
    }
    public string Description => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) || Name == "When" || Name == "MapWhen" || Name == "UseMiddleware" ?
                                 $"Inline middleware, registered at line: {RegisteredLineNumber}, in file: {ConfigFile}" : Name;
    public IMiddlewareInfo NextMiddlewareInfo { get; private set; }
    public void SetNextMiddlewareInfo(IMiddlewareInfo nextMiddlewareInfo)
    {
        NextMiddlewareInfo = nextMiddlewareInfo;
    }
}
```

Second we declare a wrapper class for `IApplicationBuilder` to help intercept the `Use` call (which is actually used to register any middlewares). This follows the adapter pattern:

```
public class ApplicationBuilderWrapper : IApplicationBuilder
{
    readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;
    readonly MethodInfo _configureMethod;        
    public ApplicationBuilderWrapper(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _app = app;
        _configureMethod = typeof(Startup).GetMethod(nameof(Startup.Configure));
    }
    public IServiceProvider ApplicationServices { get => _app.ApplicationServices; set => _app.ApplicationServices = value; }

    public IFeatureCollection ServerFeatures => _app.ServerFeatures;

    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties => _app.Properties;

    public RequestDelegate Build()
    {
        return _app.Build();
    }

    public IApplicationBuilder New()
    {
        return new ApplicationBuilderWrapper(_app.New());
    }
    LastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature _prevRegisteredMiddlewareInfo;
    public IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
    {
        //get the stub frame that is directly after the Startup.Configure method
        var middlewareUseMethodFrame = this.GetStackCallsUptoMethod(_configureMethod).LastOrDefault();
        if(middlewareUseMethodFrame == null) return _app.Use(middleware);            
        //extract the middleware name from the stub method name
        //There are special cases in which we cannot extract a meaningful name for the middleware
        //In such cases, we can only rely on possible captured info about Line Number & Filename in which the middleware is registered
        var middlewareName = extractMiddlewareName(middlewareUseMethodFrame.GetMethod());
        var registeredAtLineNo = middlewareUseMethodFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
        var configFile = middlewareUseMethodFrame.GetFileName();
        //building the middleware info
        var currentMiddlewareInfoFeature = new LastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature(middlewareName, registeredAtLineNo, configFile);
        //wire up the next info for later referencing
        _prevRegisteredMiddlewareInfo?.SetNextMiddlewareInfo(currentMiddlewareInfoFeature);
        _prevRegisteredMiddlewareInfo = currentMiddlewareInfoFeature;

        return _app.Use(wrapNext);

        string extractMiddlewareName(MethodBase useMethod)
        {
            var methodName = useMethod.Name;
            methodName = methodName.StartsWith("Use") ? methodName.Substring(3) : methodName;
            if(methodName == "Middleware")
            {                                        
                //we cannot extract the middleware type here, hope that the runtime can extract info about the line number & filename
                methodName = "UseMiddleware";
            }
            return methodName;
        }
        RequestDelegate wrapNext(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            return middleware(async context => {
                var lastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature = (ILastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature) currentMiddlewareInfoFeature.NextMiddlewareInfo ?? currentMiddlewareInfoFeature;
                //add the feature to help identify the last run middleware                    
                context.Features.Set(lastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature);
                Debug.WriteLine($">>> entering middleware: {lastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature.Description}");
                await next(context);
                Debug.WriteLine($">>> exiting middleware: {lastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature.Description}");                    
            });
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Inspects the ILastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature if any, this should be registered first so that 
    /// it cannot be by-passed by any middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="withLastRunMiddlewareInfo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IApplicationBuilder InspectLastRunMiddleware(Action<ILastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature> withLastRunMiddlewareInfo)
    {
        _app.Use(async (context,next) => {
            await next();
            var lastMiddlewareInfo = context.Features.Get<ILastRunMiddlewareInfoFeature>();
            if(lastMiddlewareInfo != null)
            {
                withLastRunMiddlewareInfo(lastMiddlewareInfo);
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
}
```

Extension methods for getting the stacktrace info:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<StackFrame> GetStackFramesUptoMethod(this object o, MethodInfo methodInfo, bool withMethodOnly = false)
    {            
        return new StackTrace(true).GetFrames().Where(e => !withMethodOnly || e.HasMethod())
                                   .TakeWhile(e => e.GetMethod() != methodInfo).Skip(1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<StackFrame> GetStackCallsUptoMethod(this object o, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return o.GetStackFramesUptoMethod(methodInfo, true).Skip(1);
    }
}
```

Finally here's how we use it in the `Startup.Configure` method:

```
//NOTE: here's at the very beginning of the Startup.Configure method
if (env.IsDevelopment()){ 
    app = new ApplicationBuilderWrapper(app).InspectLastRunMiddleware(lastRunMiddleware => {
            Debug.WriteLine($">>> Last run middleware: {lastRunMiddleware.Description}");
        });
}
```

Again, I would like to emphasize that middlewares are complicated in various possible ways  of registration. The solution here just tries to do its best to provide you with as much info as possible for debugging purpose only. I think it can still be improved to be better.